# update order fields magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have a use case where I need to update the order status (e.g. set to 'completed). In magento 1 I just called setStatus and then save

```
$order>setState('your_state')
$order->setStatus($status);
$order->save();
```

But for magento 2 I get "function setStatus not found"

How do I update order fields such as status and other fields in Magento 2?

Comment: my bad...not calling setState correctly (forgot hyphen "-") using $order>setState(), should be $order->setState()

Comment: $saveItem = $item->load($item['item_id'],'item_id'); $saveItem->setPrice(1); $saveItem->setBasePrice(1); $saveItem->save();
I am facing this problem with items

Answer (score 3):

Use \Magento\Sales\Model\Order class for the same. (But you should always use repository interface as Magento wont change those frequently.)

```
protected $order;
    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order
        ) {
            $this->_order = $order;
        }
```

Now in your function do something like this.

```
public function yourFunction(){
   $ordData = $this->_order->load($id=your order id here);
   $ordData->setCustomerFirstname('name goes here');
   $ordData->setCustomOrderAttribute('custom order data goes here'); 
   # set your field name instead of `setCustomOrderAttribute`
   $ordData->save();
}
```